# get a spesific html on return jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
$('#form-register').change(function() {
    var i_username = $('input#input-username').val();
    var i_password = $('input#input-password').val();
    var i_company  = $('input#input-company').val();
    var i_phone    = $('input#input-phone').val();
    $.post("home", { 
        username : i_username,
        password : i_password,
        company  : i_company,
        phone    : i_phone,
        register : 'helloworld' 
    }, function(return_data){
        $('body').html(return_data);
    });
});
```

ok the question maybe is on the `$('body').html(return_data);` can we get a specific html from the return data ? example #errordiv that contains my error list if exist then somehow append on my page ? or is there another better way to do it ?

Thanks for looking in,

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: what exactly the returned data? the server side part?

Comment: yeah. is that a problem ? still cant make it work but.

Comment: I'm asking you to post that data here, or the server side part? are you using `json_encode` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(return_data)` will give you html structure

and `$(return_data).find('#errordiv')` will give you "error div" element

Comment: To complete the answer: `$(return_data).find('#errordiv').appendTo("#someDivOnThisPage")`

Comment: still returns nothing. let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can append errordiv

```
<ul id="tmp">
<li>Name</li>
<li>Address</li>
</ul>
```

then use

```
$('<li>Error</li>').prependTo('#tmp');
```

will give

```
<ul id="tmp">
    <li>Error</li>
<li>Name</li>
<li>Address</li>
</ul>
```